# Which one of these is correct sentence if there are any?

Tags: grammaticality, whose

We're having a discussion about which of these three sentences is the correct one. The context is about chocolates. That's what's going to be sticked in mouth.

So, here are the sentences.

1) Tag someone you would stick it in their mouth.

2) Tag someone whose mouth you'd like to stick it in.

3) Tag someone in whose mouth you'd like to stick it in.

I've added the picture that triggered the discussion.

[image]

Comment: #2 is the correct one. Their mouth is the mouth you would like to stick the thing into.

Comment: Tag someone into whose mouth you'd like to stick it. This is #2 without the trailing preposition. #1 is all mixed up, and #3 has "in" twice.

Comment: @macdo 3 without the final "in" would also be as correct as 2. However they are clumsy and poorly phrased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sentence 1 runs into problems because it's joining together two independent clauses: 
"tag someone", and "you would stick it in their mouth".

This is why you're helped by the relative clause (by adding 'whose') as you've attempted in sentences 2 and 3. Of the sentences you've listed only #2 is grammatically correct. In sentence 3 you've put one too many prepositions and can omit the last 'in'. 
Instead of using the the pronoun 'it' you might be better served using the demonstrative pronoun 'this'.

> A) Tag someone in whose mouth you'd like to stick this.

or

> B) Tag someone whose mouth you'd like to stick this in.

Some maintain that you shouldn't end a sentence with a preposition as I have in sentence B, so you might be better off with sentence A.

Also are you sure this picture isn't a euphemism...?

Answer (score 0):

The following are correct.

1) Tag someone, in(to) whose mouth you would stick it.

2) Tag someone whose mouth you'd like to stick it in(*to*).

You may say: "to stick in" (= insert) or "to stick into" (= thrust, shove)

By the way, it's "stick" and "stuck" (*past, past participle*)